# Is the Washington D.C. metrorail day pass valid for buses?

Tags: washington-dc

The website seems to suggest that the day pass is only valid for rail.

https://www.wmata.com/fares/farecard-options.cfm

> One Day Pass $14.50  Pass available on SmarTrip® cards is valid for
>   one day of unlimited Metrorail travel;

But that seems a bit strange for a day pass. Can someone who has used it recently please confirm?

Comment: The only WMATA pass that is good for bus as well as rail is, well, the SelectPass [Rail with Bus Pass](https://www.wmata.com/fares/SelectPass.cfm), which is a monthly pass aimed at commuters. All others are for one mode or the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because it clearly says

> is valid for one day of unlimited Metrorail travel

Metrorail is not WMATA bus.

PS.
The price of this pass for the value it offers is ridiculous, I know.

Answer (score 6):

This came up on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g28970-i40-k7698252-Metro_Card_question-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html):

> Can you use a one day smartrip card for both bus and metro?
>
> Passes are not a good value for a regular tourist and must be bought separately for bus and metro and loaded onto Smartrip card.